# Configure multiple datasources in Spring Boot application with multiple docker containers

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, datasource

I am currently trying to configure a spring boot application to use two different docker containers (postgres images) for two different datasources. For that, I took the code from [this Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases#multiple-databases-in-spring-boot) and copied it into a new project. I adjusted the package structure in the annotations, but I am still running into errors. While I managed to find solutions for some of them, I am now stuck.
When calling `docker-compose up`, the startup of the application crashes with an IllegalStateException after the two postgres containers started.

```
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 2022-09-23 10:01:07.835  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 2022-09-23 10:01:07.985  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 141 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 2022-09-23 10:01:07.986  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 2022-09-23 10:01:07.996  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 9 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 2022-09-23 10:01:08.251 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | 
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactoryBuilder
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/
:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.
22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.
3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at com.example.springbootdocker.multipledb.SpringBootDockerApplication.main(SpringBootDockerApplication.java:28) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.La
unchedURLClassLoader@4590c9c3]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22
]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:156) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       ... 25 common frames omitted
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategy
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       ... 41 common frames omitted
spring-boot-docker-app-1        | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
spring-boot-docker-app-1        |       ... 45 common frames omitted
[...]
```

I'm hoping to have the tables for `User` in `sourceone`, and for `Product` in `sourcetwo`. For now, all I see when I look into the db containers with `psql` is that no relations were found (I guess that's because the application is crashing which is why I'm trying to fix that).
My workflow is to run `./mvnw.exe clean install`, then build a docker image with `docker build -t test/multiple-db .` and finally run `docker-compose up`.

In the process of trying to fix other errors, I added and changed some dependencies. I read that this error might also be related to a problem with the dependencies, but I did not manage to find a solution so far.
Here are some snippets of the code which might help, most of it is very similar to the above mentioned tutorial ([github source](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-jpa-enterprise-2)). It seemed some of the dependencies were outdated which I tried to fix but maybe I have done some bigger damage in the process.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.2.9-slim
WORKDIR /opt
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:

  app:
    image: test/multiple-db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - sourceone
      - sourcetwo

  sourceone:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: user

  sourcetwo:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: product
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: product
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://sourceone:5432/user
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.second-datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://sourcetwo:5432/product
spring.second-datasource.username=product
spring.second-datasource.password=product
spring.second-datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

I hope I didn't miss anything. Thanks in advance, would love to hear some input on what I've done wrong!

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy` doesn't seem like a Docker-related problem.

Comment: My bad, I deleted the docker tag. Thanks for the heads-up and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping both container ports to the same 5432 of host. Use 2 different ports and also include the changed ports inside application.properties file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed the ports of the second container to 5433 but I'm still getting the same error message. I found another leftover error in the application.properties file (forgot to change the url of the second datasource back to .../sourcetwo.. (didn't help though)).

Comment: Can you use another jdk image not a slim.

Comment: Thanks again. Changing the jdk image (tried non-slim and a different version too) didn't help sadly.